# Why text size is different in these 2 files in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, font-size

I'm working on Adobe Photoshop(2019-2020).

In one file Arial Regular font size 12pt texts looks normal as in below image:

[image: Arial regular 12pt]

But in the another file the at size 11pt the text is very big as shown in the next image:

[image: Arial regular 11pt]

How to change the settings to get text size back to normal as in first image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point (`pt`) is a physical size and it depends on the document resolution. I imagine between two your documents it's not the same.

Select your first document, go to `Image > Image Size` to get its `Resolution`, then switch to the second one (the one you want to change) and in the same window change the `Resolution` value to the same as your first doc.

And make sure `Resample` is turned off, otherwise the dimensions of the document will also change.

[image]

Comment: A point is 1/72 of an inch, so that at 72 px per inch, a point is approx. 1 pixel (and so 10pt type will be about 10 px). At 300 ppi, a point will be approx 4 pixels. So 10pt type will be about 40px)